# play with Integers

Tags: number-theory

If $[x]$ represents integer part of the number & $\{x\}$ represents fractional part of the number. Find the sum of all values of $x$ for which $5\cdot\{x\}=x+[x]$.

I try to determine the range of $x$ but it is quite difficult to find the sum of $x$.

Comment: It was easy, $\frac{3}{2}$ :D

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Write $x = [x]+ \{x\}$. Pluging this into your equation gives $4\{x\} = 2[x]$, or $[x] = 2\{x\}$. So $2\{x\}$ is an integer. Can you find the values of $\{x\} \in [0,1)$ for which $2\{x\}$ is an integer?

Answer (score 1):

The left side is limited by $5$, so the only possibilities are the values of $x$ for which $x<5$.

Therefore, the candidates are $[x]=0,1,2,3,4$.

- If $[x]=0$, then $\{x\}=x$ and your equation has no solution.
- If $[x] = 1$, then $\{x\} = x-1$ and the equation becomes $5(x-1) = x + 1$ with a solution $x=\frac32$.
- If $[x] = 2$, then $\{x\}=x-1$ and the equation $5(x-2) = x + 2$ has a solution $x=3$, but snce $[3]\neq 2$, there is no solution.

Can you continue?

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution. It doesn't change the sum of solutions of course.